# What is mass-assignment in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mass-assignment

I have heard couple of people complaining and posting questions about mass-assignment in Rails. I have got same error couple of times and all I did was `attr_accessible`. But what exactly is mass assignment? could somebody explain with example?

Comment: Check this out: http://railscasts.com/episodes/26-hackers-love-mass-assignment. Although it might be a little outdated, the core principles remain the same.

Comment: NOTE: **Rails 4** handles mass assignment better with [**strong parameters**](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/) in the controller instead of protections in the model. See [**this article**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/mass-assignment-rails-and-you/) for great explanation of what mass assignment is and Rails 3/4 techniques.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[Mass Assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) is the name Rails gives to the act of constructing your object with a parameters hash. It is "mass assignment" in that you are assigning multiple values to attributes via a single assignment operator.

The following snippets perform mass assignment of the `name` and `topic` attribute of the `Post` model:

```
Post.new(:name => "John", :topic => "Something")
Post.create(:name => "John", :topic => "Something")
Post.update_attributes(:name => "John", :topic => "Something")
```

In order for this to work, your model must allow mass assignments for each attribute in the hash you're passing in.

There are two situations in which this will fail:

- You have an `attr_accessible` declaration which does *not* include `:name`
- You have an `attr_protected` which *does* include `:name`

It recently became the default that attributes had to be manually white-listed via a `attr_accessible` in order for mass assignment to succeed. Prior to this, the default was for attributes to be assignable unless they were explicitly black-listed `attr_protected` or any *other* attribute was white-listed with `attr_acessible.`

It is important to consider which attributes can be mass assigned because code like this is so common:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
```

Typically this is used when the user submits a form rendered by a `form_for @post`. In an ideal world, the `params[:post]` hash should only contain the fields we displayed on the form. However, it is trivial easy for the user to pass additional fields in their request, so in effect you're allowing a user to set *any* fields on `@post`, not just the ones displayed on the form.

Failure to safely use mass assignment has led to several high profile bugs in some pretty big Rails applications, like the one that allowed somebody to [inject their own public key](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/03/GitHub-Compromised/) into the list of trusted keys on a Github repository and push code directly to a repository they should not have had access to.